# Testing navigation in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have a Silverlight application that is using a navigation frame.

I am trying to write a unit-test for that application using the Silverlight testing framework, however when I execute the test method I get the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException
No XAML was found at the location '/Pages/LoginPage.xaml'
```

The unit-test method looks like:

```
[TestMethod]
[Asynchronous]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var mainPage = new MainPage();
    WaitFor(mainPage, "Loaded");
    TestPanel.Children.Add(mainPage);
    EnqueueCallback(() => Assert.IsTrue(mainPage != null));
    EnqueueTestComplete();
}
```

Here's the MainPage.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AccurateSilverlight.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="577" d:DesignWidth="858"
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid Height="36" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Background="#FF9A9A9A">
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" 
                  Name="ModuleComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="250" IsEnabled="False" />
        <Button Content="Logout" Height="23" Margin="0,7,6,0" 
                Name="LogoutButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Width="75" IsEnabled="False" Click="LogoutButton_Click" />
    </Grid>
    <sdk:Frame Margin="0,35,0,0" Name="NavigationFrame" 
               Source="/Pages/LoginPage.xaml" 
               Navigated="NavigationFrame_Navigated" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If I run the "main" xap the application works correctly. I just have that error while testing.

I suspect the error is due to the unit-test framework executing its xap and embedding my xap in it, but cannot figure out a way to get around that.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/Pages/LoginPage.xaml` is relative to your current assembly. You will need to fully qualify your route using [pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx).

The end result should be something like this: `/AccurateSilverlight;component/Pages/LoginPage.xaml`